# Multiple info windows showing same text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have implemented infoWindow to show data of my multiple markers. But all i can display is same data in all by info windows .

How to show data which is related to that marker, so that there should be no repetition ?

Here is my code :

```
     for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonDataDict.count; i ++) {
        NSDictionary *newDict = [jsonDataDict objectAtIndex:i ];

        double latitude = [[newDict valueForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
        double longitute = [[newDict valueForKey:@"lng"]doubleValue];


      nameStr = [newDict valueForKey:@"name"];


      countJson = i ;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitute);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
        marker.title = [newDict valueForKey:@"name"];
      //  marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin11.png"];
        marker.icon = [self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinPopoye.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(75.0f, 60.0f)];
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(1.1, 0.70);
        marker.map = self.mapView;
        [self mapView:self.mapView markerInfoWindow:marker];


    }
}

- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 25)];
   customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:71.0/255.0 green:65.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:0.8];
    customView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    customView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    //  Orange Color ==== [UIColor colorWithRed:254.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0 blue:4.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
       UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 10)];
   nameLabel.text = nameStr;
   nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
    [customView addSubview:nameLabel];

      return customView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this statement:

```
nameLabel.text = nameStr;
```

with:

```
nameLabel.text = marker.title;
```

The problem is your using a shared `NSString`, `nameStr`, which gets overwritten at each iteration of your `for` loop. So, all label share the same string value when they are finally displayed. You could also do:

```
nameLabel.text = [nameStr copy];
```

and it should work -- but I think that using `nameStr` in your code was just a remnant of some previous "hack".

Comment: [nameStr copy ] doest make any difference .